# React Router Dom v6 - Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Im trying to upgrade to v6 of react router dom. The application works but I cant seem to get the testcases to work.

Before we had this wrapper for jest:

```
const render = (ui: React.FC, path: string, route: string): RenderResult => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] });
    const queryClient = new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
            queries: {
                retry: false,
            },
        },
    });

    return {
        ...render(
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Route path={path} component={ui} />
                </Router>
            </QueryClientProvider>,
        ),
    };
};
```

After following the documentation for v6 I got the application to work and I updated the wrapper for jest to the following solution:

```
return {
        ...render(
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path={path} element={ui} />
                    </Routes>
                </Router>
            </QueryClientProvider>,
        ),
    };
```

This results in the following error:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if
> you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe
> you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Majority of the components in the project are function components. So getting this to work is kinda vital. :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax for rendering a component into a `Route` in RRDv6 is as a JSX literal instead of as a reference to the component.

Example:

```
<Route path="/thepath" element={<MyComponent />} />
```

For your example it's the `ui` component that must be rendered as JSX. Rename `ui` to `Ui` so it's a valid React component and render accordingly.

```
const render = (Ui: React.FC, path: string, route: string): RenderResult => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] });
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        retry: false,
      },
    },
  });

  return {
    ...render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
          <Route
            path={path}
            element={<Ui />} // <-- JSX, not reference
          />
        </Router>
      </QueryClientProvider>,
    ),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Always return like a component and not like a function.**

✅Correct implementation-

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop/>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

❌Wrong implementation-

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={Home} />
    <Route path="/shop" element={Shop} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```